# String.join starting and ending index

Tags: vb.net

Can I specify the starting and Ending Index in String.Join ?
Just to clarify, say I have array A (dimensioned 0 to 20) and I would like to join elements 4 to 10, can this be done with String.Join?
The way I currently do it is

```
Dim Str as String
Str = ""
For I = 4 to 10
   Str = Str & A(I)
Next
```

Is there an alternative to this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to extract only the array subset you want and pass it to String.Join in a single line of code.

```
Dim Str = String.Join("", a.Skip(3).Take(7))
```

(By the way, this has also the added benefit that if your array doesn't contain 10 elements you don't get an IndexOutOfRange exception)